# Can a list of needed nugets be sorted not to crash when Package Manager is trying to install them from command line?

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I am getting the latest version of a project from TFS. The nuget packages do not come through.

The rebuild fails because of missing nuget package. When I download, add the right nuget one by one from Nuget Manager, the error goes away, and an other one shows up. Not all of them are "root level" nugets (not sure what they are called), some of them are nugets under nuget.

Anyway, looking at the Package Manager command line installation, it works faster, but the problem is that I need to run them in a specific order,otherwise install doesn't go through because of dependencies.

I checked the list in a json file from a coworker, and there are hundreds to install.

Is there a way to make this go faster?

Note: I want to use the same specific versions as the coworker, not to cause any issues later on

Comment: Did you use packages.config nuget management format or packagesreference?

Comment: You should right-click on the solution-->`restore nuget packages` and it will restore the missing packages and you do not have to reinstall them(complex).

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I did that after every nuget I downloaded

Comment: if you clone your project from your TFS into the local, the project miss the nuget packages but the csproj has referenced them, so you should use restore to make the nuget packages on your local pc.  Installing nuget packages is that you did not have it on the local and also on the csproj file. Run `update-package -reinstall` under `Tools`--> `Nuget Package Manager `-->`Package Manager Console`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such order list function to help install a set of nuget packages in a certain order.

What I know is that using `update-package -reinstall` under **Package Manager Console**.

That command will reinstall all the nuget packages and their dependencies in a sequence automatically.

It will not block your vs process and cause accidental errors. You only need to wait for the process, the time depends on the number of your nuget packages and the complexity of the dependencies.

Comment: I will mark this as Accepted answer, however I cannot try this right now, as I did what I had to do one by one, manually. If I will ever get this issue again, and will be able to try your suggestion, I will come back and update